# Rendering a scene or prefab in a gallery style view in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#, scene

I'm working on a project that is a bit like YouTube where someone browses some content, clicks on one and sees it in the youtube player while still seeing the rest of the content.

In my case the content is a Unity prefab that runs with interactions and gameplay, a bit like an interactive YouTube.

Is there a way to load these prefabs in a scene or something and have them displayed in a view port of some sort which substitutes the position of the player?

Comment: [Cross posting to Stack Overflow is discouraged](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/75627). ([SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124788/rendering-a-scene-or-prefab-in-a-gallery-style-view-in-unity3d))